# Ubuntu 14.04 + VMware 6: Left Ctrl and Right Shift not functioning

Tags: unity, keyboard, vmware

Before I launch a virtual machine in VMware, all the modifier keys function properly. Even when I launch VMware, but before I start the virtual machine everything works great.

However once I start a virtual machine my **left Ctrl** and **right Shift** keys stop functioning. They simply have no affect.

Here are a few observations that might lead to something:

- My **left Shift** still keeps working.
- I mapped my **Caps Lock to Ctrl** and it works properly.
- Executing `sudo setxkbmap` temporarily sets everything in order. Once VMware gains focus and I type something, problem comes back.
- Problem persists even after I quit VMware.

This is the first time I'm using Unity (I have been using Gnome for a long time) and I'm suspecting the problem is related to that. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I'm seeing almost the exact same symptoms. ubuntu 14.04, Vmware workstation 10.0.3. Except my shift keys still work, both ctrl keys stop working. Caps-lock remapped to ctrl still works (as ctrl). Hardware id Dell xps 15 l521x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR:**

In Gnome Tweak Tool, set "Ctrl key position" to "Caps Lock as Ctrl" and "Caps Lock key behavior" to "Caps Lock is disabled".

**Full story:**

The problem appears to be how Ubuntu is remapping the CapsLock key. When Gnome Tweak Tool's "Caps Lock key behavior" property is set to "Make Caps an additional Ctrl", xmodmap reports:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Caps_Lock (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The problem appears to be that *both* lock and control list "Caps_Lock (0x42)". Everything works well until you set focus into a VMWare VM (I tested using VMWare Player). After focusing VMWare's window, `xmodmap` will report an empty mapping:

```
xmodmap:  up to 0 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift     
lock      
control   
mod1      
mod2      
mod3      
mod4      
mod5
```

Running `setxkbmap` resets the keyboard mapping and temporarily resolves the issue.  Playing with `xmodmap`, I found that removing Caps_Lock (0x42) from lock stopped VMWare from flushing the keyboard mappings. *But*, Ubuntu 14.04 ignores `.Xmodmap` files, so there was no simple method to use `xmodmap`.

We can fix the root-cause of this situation by changing two settings in Gnome Tweak Tool, as described at the top of this post. Doing so will properly configure the keyboard mappings so that Caps_Lock (0x42) does not show up in two locations:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: That works. Thanks, especially for the great extensive explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help. This plagued me for months. You can find lots of other folks suffering from this by searching for "VMWare keyboard fubar".  I've found people having this problem (though perhaps with a different root cause) all the way back to 2008.  I'm surprised that, so far as I can tell, this post represents the only documented solution to the CapsLock specific variant of the "VMWare keyboard fubar" bug.

Comment: Thanks that works for me

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem for YEARS. You are amazing.

Comment: This also fixes caps lock being remapped to control not working in Citrix Workspace too